# Proof of $det(A+B)=detA + <$Cof$A,B> + <A,$Cof$B> + detB$

Tags: matrices, determinant

For $A,B \in M^{3 \times 3}$, I want to prove the following property:

$det(A+B)=detA + <$Cof$A,B> + <A,$Cof$B> + detB$ where $<.,.>$ denotes the usual inner product on $M^{3\times3}$

Any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $Cof A$? And what ist "the usual inner product on $M^{3x3}$. Do you just identify $M^{3x3}$ with $M^{9}$?

Comment: $M^{3 \times 3}$ means the set of the 3 by 3 matrices. Also Cof A means the cofactor of the matrix A @Takirion